# Getting Facebook profile picture URL from graph API for Ionic Hybrid Application

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, hybrid-mobile-app

Facebook graph API tells me I can get a profile picture of a user using

http://graph.facebook.com/100001225634061/picture?type=large

which works fine.

But If I used the same application in **iOS devices** this link is not working.

For Hybrid applications, Graph url is not redirecting in iOS.

Any solution for this? Single solution should work on both the devices.

Thanks!

Comment: Try to use https instead of http.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use **http**. You can use the **https**.

https://graph.facebook.com/100001225634061/picture?type=large